# Login Customization in RDWEB

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, remote-desktop

I have hosted application using windows server manager on rdweb and give access to specific user group in active directory the access to the rdweb.

I want to restrict users to login only from specific gateways like user A,B,C can login only from 17.45.45.1. How this is possible?

Answer (score 1):

> First you need to create a user group for specific ip address , then when a user trying to access in your site you have to check there IP Address through

```
IPHostEntry Host = default(IPHostEntry);
    string Hostname = null;
    Hostname = System.Environment.MachineName;
    Host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Hostname);
    foreach (IPAddress IP in Host.AddressList) {
        if (IP.AddressFamily == System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork) {
            IPAddress = Convert.ToString(IP);
        }
    }
```

Comment: But I am using rdweb default page how can I edit that

Comment: you are trying to give access from a specific IP address so you need to edit in your code .you have to put restriction in your code

Comment: sir I have rdweb page How can I customize it is connected to active directory how can I change its login page

Comment: This two link might help you. 
[solved-how-to-customize-your-rds-rdweb-page](https://www.urtech.ca/2018/03/solved-how-to-customize-your-rds-rdweb-page/)
[solved-how-to-remove-rdweb-from-the-rds-login-page-url] (https://www.urtech.ca/2018/03/solved-how-to-remove-rdweb-from-the-rds-login-page-url/)